# Excel truncating large numbers

Tags: excel, vba

How to prevent Excel from truncating numbers when pasted into a cell?

```
Example: 425051703060011006
```

Comment: No, it changes the last digit to a 0.

Comment: You cannot if you want to maintain the numeric data type.  Excel's limitations are 15 digits.  You can only do it if you treat the numeric value as text.  So the question is what you need to do with this value.  If it is an account number, then text is fine.  If it is to be used in further calculations, then you'll need some kind of extended precision routine in VBA.

Comment: Yes, this is for order numbers that I receive that represent account names and become corrupted without additional code to handle these types of numbers.

Comment: Then just format that column (or those cells) as ***Text*** before you paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this answer. First, yes the cell should be formatted as text before pasting the value into the cell. But also, if it is the initial time that you are adding the value to the sheet, you should select the cell then paste the number into the formula bar. This will strip it of any formats that it brings with it and it will then display correctly.

Comment: The question doesn't mention anything about the value being anything other than a number such as `425051703060011006` - formats don't seem to play any part in this.  (If the OP was copying a cell containing that number, they wouldn't have a problem, so they are obviously just pasting an unformatted number.)  Your answer should simply state that the cell needs to be formatted as text prior to pasting and, to ensure that the question isn't off-topic, show a programming solution to doing so - i.e. the answer by Gary's Student.

Answer (score 3):

Either place a single quote in front of the number prior to pasting or format the destination cell to *Text* before pasting:

```
Sub qwerty()
    ActiveSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
End Sub
```